# Android webview doesn't open api.whatsapp

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to open an api.whatsapp link from my webpage using the Android web view but I faced the error  `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

I have changed the shouldOverrideUrlLoading method several times trying to fix it but the intent never works. Have someone faced the same problem before?

This is the current version of my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   // public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private WebView mywebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://mypage");
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    }

    public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //String url = request.getUrl().toString();
                if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://mypage")) {
                    return false;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Add Validating to your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method like:

```
Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

Comment: I changed the method shouldOverrideUrlLoading including your recommendation but it still doesn't work. :(